# Fonts and images cannot be resolved after expo eject

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native, expo

**Problem**

I just recently ejected from expo in a forked repository, and ran into an issue when trying to build the iOS app, being unable to resolve my existing image and font assets.

**Steps**

npm install

expo eject

yarn ios

**Expected Results**

Application runs after pods are installed and dependencies are cleared.

**Actual Results**
[image]

I tried commenting out the lines where I import my fonts to see if it's an issue with these files, but images I attempt to resolve have the same issue. Here's my App.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AppNavigator from './navigation/AppNavigator.js';
import AppIntroSlider from 'react-native-app-intro-slider';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsmobile from './aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsmobile);

import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import rootReducer from './store/reducers/rootReducer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';

// Accessing the store and associated components
// If adding additional dispatching action files, ensure they are added to the rootReducer
 const store = createStore(
   rootReducer,
   composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
 );

 // Fonts that need to be used in the application
const fetchFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    'euclid-triangle': require('./assets/fonts/EuclidTriangle-Regular.ttf'),
    'euclid-triangle-bold': require('./assets/fonts/EuclidTriangle-Bold.ttf'),
    'euclid-triangle-semibold': require('./assets/fonts/EuclidTriangle-SemiBold.ttf'),
  });
};

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    // Load the font if it has not been done already
    if (!this.state.fontLoaded) {
      return (
        <AppLoading startAsync={fetchFonts}
          onFinish={() => {this.setState({fontLoaded: true})
          }}/>
      )
    }

    // If the intro slider has been dismissed the main app can be shown
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppNavigator/>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Ejecting Expo doesn't help, at least based on a previous experience,
my advice is to create a new project from scratch, remove everything related to expo, and leave non-expo dependencies,
as for Font on IOS, you have to add them as resources

please refer to this link for adding Custom fonts on IOS: [here](https://medium.com/react-native-training/adding-custom-fonts-to-react-native-b266b41bff7f)